# hide several columns after cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Im trying unsucesfully to hide several columns (C:I), show J and hide (K:Z), show AA, hide (AB:AT) only if B2 = " Financial years", if anyone can help with this would be really apreciate it.

Thanks
Elliott

Comment: Welcome to the community. Could you clarify your question regarding your usecase or at least demostrate with a screenshot? There're also some typos here.

Comment: Go to the documentation and search on hide.